How to cook fbx mesh in Nvidia Physx 4.1?
I have two fbx files one concave, the other convex. I want to load them using assimp and then cook both with Physx 4.1. How can i cook a mesh using Nvidia Physx 4.1 ?

@user24714692 The first link is broken
